# Email the Sales team their monthly Commission at an Order level

Tags: sql

I am trying to find a way in SQL which would send email either as excel attachment or html to the Sales Teams on how much monthly commission did they earn on each order.  Since it is commission, due to security reasons I cannot send a common file to everyone to look at each others commissions. Trying to put the scenario in a tabular form for a better understanding.

The first table gives you at an Order level who is getting paid how much. Which I already have in place

[image: Table 1 - Overall Commission Table]

This table gives how much commission is paid individually and should email the same results to respective Sales Person based on Email address listed in 1st table

[image: Results - Split of individual Sales person and their commission]

Comment: MySQL or SQL Server? They are completely different!

Comment: You should edit and update your question to include the sample data and the expected output in the text format.

Comment: I've removed the conflicting RDBMS tags, please add back the relevant one.

Comment: You can look at this post : https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/846204/How-To-Send-Mail-Using-SQL-Server-Part

Comment: Pankaj_Dwevedi - Thanks for your reply. Checked the link, the solution there is a generic one and tells me how to configure to send an email. But then does not deal with my scenario. The solution needs to send email to every sales guy with their Orders and what was commission individually.